# iOS Appdelegate field population and object creation

Tags: objective-c, appdelegate

I am new to iOS and was trying to wrap my head around the functionality of Appdelegate callback's and field population.

So here's what I am doing:
declaring a global property in Appdelegate's header

```
@property NSString* GlobalUsername;
```

Populating the value to this property in one on of the callbacks

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {

            _GlobalUsername = @"username";

}
```

Now in the ViewControler's button click method, I am creating an object of AppDelegate, accessing GlobalUsername and showing it on the screen using textView.

```
- (IBAction)ShowDetails:(id)sender
{
    AppDelegate *appdelegate = (AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;


    NSString* details=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Username is : %@",appdelegate.GlobalUsername];
[_textView setText:details];

}
```

Now what I don't understand is that how is the value of GlobalUsername is being associated with the object of AppDelegate. GlobalUsername was populated when application became active and not when I created an instance of the Appdelegate so how does the object returned by sharedApplication method still has this information encapsulated with it?

Comment: `sharedApplication` is using the "Singleton Pattern". It's not creating a new instance of `AppDelegate`. Look for more info of that pattern. In Objective-C, we usually declare it in our own class `+(id)sharedInstance;` (you can find a lot a code naming it like that or similar naming).

Comment: That makes sense. I have a rough idea of the singletons. Am I correct in assuming that an instance of the Appdelegate is already created in memory when the app is launched and during the lifecycle of the app this same exact instance is passed around and can be accessed using Appdelegate's sharedInstance method?

Comment: @nitinsh99, yeah, you are absolutely right

Comment: Yes. You can log "%p" to check that it's the same address, or check in the debugger. Look also how we create them (for custom purpose), using `dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{ singleton = [[Object alloc] init];});` and what it does exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`delegate` of `UIApplication` works according to singleton pattern. There is only 1 instance every time you try to get it. For example:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];
...Any API requests...
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];
```

If UIApplication's delegate will be different every time it won't save state of network indicator.